# Number of Guesses Cannot Be The Same In Binary Search with Even Numbers

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

I don't understand how many times it takes for the worst case while binary searching. Some say log2(n), some say log2(n) + 1. However, I don't understand this. Let me illustrate:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 (Correct number is 10, for instance)

Guess: 5 - higher
Guess: 8 - higher
Guess: 9 - higher
Guess: 10 - correct
```

It took log<sub>2</sub>n guesses. (rounded up because you can't guess 3.3219280949 of times)

Assume the number is 1:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Guess: 5 - lower
Guess: 2 - lower
Guess: 1 - correct
```

So depending on what you choose as middle point, it'll always be one more or one less than each other but in the books I read or in the class, they don't say so. I'm really confused, can someone please explain what's going on?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. You have to read more about asymptotic notation.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that, if the output of every guess carries exactly one bit of information (like 'lower' and 'greater or equal'), then you will have to guess `ceil(log2(n))` times in worst case to *know for sure* which number is the guessed number.

In this case, the outcome of every guess can be one of 'lower' 'higher' and 'correct'. The game ends when you guess the right number. In the previous example the game ended when you know the answer for sure, but you didn't have to actually guess that. This is the difference.

Let's calculate the needed number of guesses on your case.
Let F(i) be the maximum N value using i guesses.

`F(1) = 1`, because you have only one guess, and have to guess right

For every further guess you have a chance of guessing the right number, otherwise the rest are split into two groups, so:

`F(k) = 1 + 2*F(k - 1), if k > 1`

That means `F(i) = 2**i - 1`.

The minimum number of guesses: `i = log2(F(i) + 1)`, so `F_inv(i) = ceil(log2(i + 1)) = floor(log2(i)) + 1` for every positive integer `i`